# Zoom marker but....it's moving!! O.O What the heck

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I think the problem is in the training data, as you can see below there I put the php code and the rendering to explain.

I'm new to API to Google Maps, this is not my code. Then comes the problem: when to once zoom in on this pointer moves a lot when i zooming! I can not figure out what the conflict of maps displaying. I'd like to use only LatLong to indicate the area but the script is provided to calculate the road .. this is the second hypothesis.

What I tried:

- From: `setMapAddress ("<? Php city ();?>, <? Php been ();?>, <? Php zipcode ();?>");`
- To `setMapAddress ("");`
- Result: `setMapAddress (" , , ");`

-deleting:

```
bed: "<?php beds(); ?>",
            bath: "<?php baths(); ?>",
            size: "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ct_sqft", true); ?> <?php sqftsqm(); ?>",
            street: "<?php the_title(); ?>",
            city: "<?php city(); ?>",
            state: "<?php state(); ?>",
            zip: "<?php zipcode(); ?>",
```

---

Image of issue:
[image: #[Image of issue][1]]

---

[Page with script](http://pineto.contat.eu/listings/zona-industriale-scerne-di-pineto-capannone/)

```
<script>
        function setMapAddress(address) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { address : address }, function( results, status ) {
                if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                    <?php  if((get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_ct_latlng", true))) { ?>
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_ct_latlng", true); ?>);
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                    <?php } ?>
                    var options = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: location,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo strtoupper($ct_options['ct_contact_map_type']); ?>, 
                        streetViewControl: true
                    };
                    var mymap = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), options );   
                    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                        map: mymap, 
                        draggable: false,
                        flat: true,
                        labelContent: '',
                        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                        labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
                        labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
                        icon: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/blank.png',
                        <?php  if((get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_ct_latlng", true))) { ?>  
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_ct_latlng", true); ?>)
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                        <?php } ?>
                    });     
                }
            });
        }
        setMapAddress( "<?php city(); ?>, <?php state(); ?>, <?php zipcode(); ?>" );
        </script>
        <div id="map"></div>
```

This code was rendered as:

```
<script>
        function setMapAddress(address) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { address : address }, function( results, status ) {
                if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.608120,14.067420);
                                        var options = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: location,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                        streetViewControl: true
                    };
                    var mymap = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), options );   
                    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                        map: mymap, 
                        draggable: false,
                        flat: true,
                        labelContent: '',
                        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                        labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
                        labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
                        icon: 'http://pineto.contat.eu/wp-content/themes/th/images/blank.png',

                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.608120,14.067420)
                                            });     
                }
            });
        }
        setMapAddress( ", , " );
        </script>
```

Comment: Use markdown "#" for emphasis not capital letters

Comment: It's just a smile... O.o

Comment: I was talking about your links.

Comment: Ok, sorry... edit aproved :)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks... but the problem remain...

Comment: Would be setting a maximum zoom be a solution, do users need to see the continent of Europe?

Comment: Yeah, i know but the problem is with the close-up view....try on live demo...I'm afraid that the customer does not understand what is the correct position of the marker ... To tell the truth I do not understand it myself trying to zoom in to the maximum .. see who moves from northern Italy to central Italy OO

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. Are you familiar with http://jsfiddle.net/? Could you build an example there so I could try to fix it?

Comment: Ok, i'm try to remake it... I'm working on this file: http://jsfiddle.net/DU4Bc/

Comment: I think the problem is with your image. Don't change your code!

Comment: I thought of that too but then I do not know why I threw the code ... seen that the icons do not understand anything. And then I did the back-up before you change anything;) do not worry ... it would be better if I could say be happy. Gives me no peace this problem.

Comment: here my script simplified version... http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mtpma/

Comment: **But what image? The icon or the hidden ...**

Comment: The icon. Try my updated version: http://i.imgur.com/EJtyNPN.png if it works I'll post it as an answer so you can accept.

Comment: ok, i'm going to try youyt icon :)

Comment: Good luck. We failed to avoid extended discussions in comments :P

Comment: At least we tried .... here's how you can see nothing has changed. Thanks anyway :) http://pineto.contat.eu/listings/572/                    No one who understands these maps can help me?

Comment: Can you use the default Google maps marker? Does it work with that?

Comment: At least I got one badge (CUSTODIAN) from this topic xD

Comment: I do not know what I should delete .. but i try now!

Comment: Hahahahaha is that from the edits? :D

Comment: Yes! Often edit posts because I am Italian and sometimes Google Translate makes jokes xD

Comment: Yeah I could tell...I don't think anyone speaks English like Google Translate

Comment: Anyways, I think you solved your own problem because the jsfiddle you posted doesn't have the same behavior as your site, so if you use same map that you used for the jsfiddle you should be fine.

Comment: .label { height: 51px; width: 47px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; padding: 1px 4px; background: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/map-pin.png) no-repeat;}

Comment: Whoa the marker is done in CSS? Is that the right way to have custom markers?

Comment: It's one of my dubd, css for marker!! Now that I've deleted the image seems that the marker does not move .... And fixed on the City of Pineto ... :) perhaps we are close to the solution :)) Now I have a hope :P

Comment: You may want to read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/training/customizing/custom-markers

Comment: I think the question to ask now is .. how to remove the marker?

Comment: Replace blank.png with my icon.

Comment: II-have already replaced with youre icon. OK, i'm going to read... I think that today I do not sleep :O Thanks for the guidance ...

Comment: You're welcome. Did my icon work?

Comment: Nah! But what bad luck ... see you too: http://pineto.contat.eu/listings/572/

Comment: `var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   map: self.map, 
   draggable: false,
   flat: true,
   labelContent: property.price,
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
   icon: 'wp-content/themes/reale/images/blank.png',   
   position: latlng
   });`

Comment: You didn't change it. Change `icon: 'wp-content/themes/reale/images/blank.png'` to `icon: 'http://pineto.contat.eu/wp-content/themes/th/images/map-pin.png'`, and get rid of the marker css.

Comment: It's your image .. I changed the name before uploading and I replaced it. and deleted the css

Comment: It worked. Get rid of the css for the marker. Make sure you do a hard refresh.

Comment: I did ctrl + alt + delete with chrome ... but to no avail, look what happened deleting the css. The zoom moves all the same ... : P Ok, now only God can save us.

Comment: I'm sure that it worked I will send you a screenshot.

Comment: Here is the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/9Y5FOYJ.png

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHH THANKLS A LOT :)))) YOU SAVE ME :) ThANKS Yupppi ole yrra :) stupid css .... TAks howderek...

Comment: How to vote? For your solution..

Comment: I posted it as an answer. upvote and accept please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the image.

First get rid of the following css (layout.css, line 151):

```
font-weight: bold; color: #fff; padding: 1px 4px; background: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/map-pin.png) no-repeat;}
```

Then, make sure this javascript (mapping.js, line 26):

`icon: 'wp-content/themes/reale/images/blank.png',`

points to my marker image.

Comment: But now i have the some issue on: http://pineto.contat.eu/?ct_property_type=0&ct_beds=0&ct_baths=0&ct_status=0&ct_price_from=&ct_price_to=&ct_additional_features=0&search-listings=true XD

Comment: However, this theme for wordpress i didn't maked xD It would be this: http://themeforest.net/item/wp-pro-real-estate-4-responsive-wordpress-theme/2912564
I modified it a bit .. but I can not correct the error map.

Comment: Oh I see. Try gettting rid of div.label on line 116 of layout.css

Comment: I do not want to bother you too much ... Now I try to fix it yourself. Then if I can not place qiu .. if you want then you can help me again (if necessary).

Comment: I'm going to dine: turnovers. See you tomorrow :) Thanks again and I think we made the record of the comments in one place ... no? It would take another badge now xD

Comment: Have a nice meal, and Welcome to Stack Overflow!